# Using angularJS with requireJS - cannot read property 'module' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, requirejs, angular-routing

I had started writing an app using angularJS. After a few weeks, I suddenly realized that I should have used require JS from the beginning to load my modules. Yes, I know, it was stupid. But it is what it is.
So I've tried to convert my code to suit requireJS now.

This is my main.js

```
requirejs.config({
baseUrl: "js",
paths: {
    jquery:'jquery-1.7.min',
    angular: 'angular',
    angularRoute:'angular-route',
    mainApp:'AngularApp/app'

},
 priority:['angular'],
shim:{

    angularRoute:{
        deps:["angular"]
    },
    mainApp:{
        deps:['angularRoute']
    }
}});

require(['angular','angularRoute', 'mainApp'],
    function(angular, angularRoute, app)
    {
        angular.bootstrap(document, ['ServiceContractModule']);
    });
```

This is my app.js

```
define(['angular',
    'angularRoute',
    'AngularApp/services',
    'AngularApp/directives',
    'AngularApp/controllers'],
    function(angular, angularRoute, services, directives, controllers)
    {
        console.log("sup");
        var serviceContractModule = angular.module('ServiceContractModule',[ 'ngRoute', services, directives, controllers ]);
        serviceContractModule.config(function($routeProvider,$locationProvider) {
            $routeProvider.when('/contractNumber/:contractNumbers', {
                controller : 'ContractController',
                templateUrl : './contractSearchResult',
                reloadOnSearch : true
            }).when('/serialNumber/:serialNumbers', {
                controller : 'SerialController',
                templateUrl : './serialSearchResult'
            }).when('/QuoteManager',{
                controller : 'QuoteManagerController',
                templateUrl: './quoteManagerView'
            }).when('/QuoteManagerHome',{
                controller : 'QuoteManagerController',
                templateUrl: './quoteManagerHome'
            });
        });

        return serviceContractModule;
    });
```

This is my directives.js file

```
define(['angular',
    'AngularApp/Directives/tableOperations',
    'AngularApp/Directives/line',
    'AngularApp/Directives/listOfValues'],
    function(
    angular,
    tableOperations,
    line,
    listOfValues)
    {
        var directiveModule = angular.module('ServiceContractModule.directives');
        directiveModule.directive('tableoperations', tableOperations);
        directiveModule.directive('line', line);
        directiveModule.directive('listOfValues', listOfValues);
        return directiveModule;
    }
```

)

And this is my services.js file

```
define(['angular',
    'AngularApp/Services/quoteManagerSearch'],
    function(angular, quoteManagerSearch)
    {
        var serviceModule = angular.module('ServiceContractModule.services');
        serviceModule.factory('searchRequestHandler', quoteManagerSearch);
        return serviceModule;
    }
```

)

When I run my page, the current error I am getting is

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'module' of undefined directives.js:14
>
> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'module' of undefined services.js:5

This seems to be happening on this particular line

```
var directiveModule = angular.module('ServiceContractModule.directives');
```

I think for some reason, the angular file is not getting loaded. Although when I run the page, I can see all the js files being loaded in the correct order in chrome.

Any ideas guys? Need quick help! Thanks!

Comment: Change angular to $angular

Comment: Umm, but I have defined the alias for the angular module as 'angular' itself. Why would I need to do that?

Comment: did you call the angular reference script?

Comment: Yes. In the main.js, I have specified in paths, angular:'angular'. The path for the angular file is js/angular.js. I have specified the baseurl as js. Furthermore, when I load the page, I can actually see the angular.js file being loaded after the main.js.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looking at the sources for Angular, I do not see anywhere that it calls RequireJS' `define` so you need a shim for it. Add this to your `shim` configuration:

```
angular: {
    exports: "angular"
}
```

By the way, the `priority` field in your configuration is obsolete. Either you use RequireJS 2.x which ignores this field because `priority` is supported only by RequireJS 1.x. Or you use RequireJS 1.x which would honor `priority` but would ignore the `shim` field because `shim` was introduced in 2.x. My suggestion: use RequireJS 2.x and remove `priority`.

Comment: Hey, thanks so much. That makes a lot of sense. I removed the priority and added the exports property for angular. Now I seem to be getting a timeout error for angularRoute and mainApp. AngularRoute doesn't seem to load after the angular file. Is there a problem with my dependencies?

Comment: There's nothing that jumps at me from what I can see in your question. When you check the network requests your browser makes, is it downloading the right stuff for `angularRoute` and `mainApp`?

Comment: Nope. It loads main.js, then angular.js and stops. I've also added the exports property for the angularRoute. Either way, I tried it with and without. Same error both times.

Comment: If the module you load as `mainApp` is the same module that you refer to with "This is my app.js", then you do not need a `shim` configuration for it because you use `define` to define it. This could explain some of the issues you are experiencing.

Comment: Yeah I did that. But something weird happened. App.js seems to load before angular. That's really weird, as I've mentioned that in my define tag in app.js. And the same earlier problem persists for angularRoute. Just doesn't load. All the other modules seem to load though. This is some pretty weird behaviour. Maybe some other files are getting imported somewhere else and causing some issues.

Comment: It is okay if `app.js` *loads* before `angular`. RequireJS loads it, executes the `define`, sees that it needs `angular` (and other stuff) and loads `angular` and the other dependencies and *then* executes the factory function (the callback passed to `define`). What is not okay is if the factory function passed to `define` *executes* before `angular` is loaded. As for `angularRoute`, is there a `define` call in it? If yes, then no shim needed.

Comment: Oh okay. angular-route.js is a library file, just like angular.js. But it should be loaded after angular.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 possible problems with your setup:
1. You are bootstrapping angular in your `main.js` and then loading the dependencies.
2. You should be referencing the dependency using string

So, after removing the `angular.bootstrap` from your `main.js`, try the following:

**app.js**

```
define([
    'AngularApp/services',
    'AngularApp/directives',
    'AngularApp/controllers'],
    function()
    {
        console.log("sup");
        var serviceContractModule = angular.module('ServiceContractModule',[ 'ngRoute', 'ServiceContractModule.services', 'ServiceContractModule.directives', '<<Your Controller Module Name>>' ]);
        serviceContractModule.config(function($routeProvider,$locationProvider) {
            $routeProvider.when('/contractNumber/:contractNumbers', {
                controller : 'ContractController',
                templateUrl : './contractSearchResult',
                reloadOnSearch : true
            }).when('/serialNumber/:serialNumbers', {
                controller : 'SerialController',
                templateUrl : './serialSearchResult'
            }).when('/QuoteManager',{
                controller : 'QuoteManagerController',
                templateUrl: './quoteManagerView'
            }).when('/QuoteManagerHome',{
                controller : 'QuoteManagerController',
                templateUrl: './quoteManagerHome'
            });
        });

        angular.bootstrap(document, ['ServiceContractModule']);
    });
```

Check out `angularAMD` that I created to help the use of RequireJS and AngularJS:
http://marcoslin.github.io/angularAMD/