# Why is my 'app' module 'is not defined' in a controller after routing with angular-route and implementing RequireJS?

Tags: angularjs, requirejs, angular-routing

I've decided to try and learn RequireJS, so I'm trying to implement it on a project where I've also decided to use Angular and Angular-Route for routing.

I've managed to set up a single module in my app.js, but after adding my first route and setting up the controller for that route 'app' is not defined within the controller.

It appears that I somehow need to either set up 'app' as a dependency for 'homeCtrl' or I need to make the 'app' module available somehow.  I am just unsure on how to do this.

Here is what is set up so far:

index.html... (*head blah blah)...

```
  <body ng-app="MyApp">

    <div ng-view>

    </div>

    <script data-main="./app/config" src="./app/require.js"></script>
    <script>
      require(['config'], function() {
        require(['app/app']);
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

app/config.js...

```
requirejs.config({
  baseUrl: './',
  paths: {
    jquery: 'lib/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min',
    bootstrap: 'lib/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min',
    angular: 'lib/bower_components/angular/angular.min',
    angular_route: 'lib/bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.min',
    home: 'app/controllers/homeCtrl'
  }
});
```

app/app.js...

```
"use strict";

define(['jquery', 'angular', 'angular_route', 'home'], function ($, angular, angular_route, home) {

  let app = angular.module('MyApp', ['ngRoute']);

  app.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
      when('/home', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/home.html',
        controller: 'homeCtrl'
      }).
      otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/home'
    });
  }]);

// End RequireJS 'define' 
});
```

app/controllers/homeCtrl.js...

```
"use strict";

define(['jquery', 'angular'], function ($, angular) {

  app.controller('homeCtrl', [
    '$scope',

    function ($scope) {
      $('body').html(`<div>Hey it worked!</div>`);

    }
  ]);
// End 'define'
});
```

Screen shot of errors in console:

[image]

Console network section showing files loaded:

[image]

Again, I'm new to using RequireJS, so I'm sure I am making a simple mistake somewhere.

Thanks for any help/solutions!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using angularJS with requireJS - cannot read property 'module' of undefined](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22033992/using-angularjs-with-requirejs-cannot-read-property-module-of-undefined)

Answer (score 0):

You need the following shim because Angular does not call `define`:

```
angular: {
    exports: "angular"
}
```